# using the total derivative to find a minimum value

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function T(x,y) where x and y are functions of t. I am given the two first order partial derivatives (dt/dx and dt/dy - the d is meant to be the partial symbol) and I am asked to use the total derivative to find a minimum value of t.

I have found the total derivative using the chain rule but I am unsure how this helps me find a minimum for t?

edit: all information given: dt/dx=6x-3y dt/dy=6y-3x
x=cos(t) y=sin(t)
**t between 0 and pi/2*

Comment: Could you write in all information you have?

Comment: dt/dx=6x-3y dt/dy=6y-3x
x=cost y=sint
0<t<pi/2

Comment: That would be best done in the question itself. =) Also, the $t$ you are constantly referring is the function $T(x,y)$ or the parameter $t$?

Comment: it is the parameter

Comment: I think what you are writing as $$\frac{dt}{dx}$$ is actually $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}.$$

Comment: yes that's what I mean - I just can't write the symbols :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $T(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are functions of a parameter $t$. In other words, we can abuse notation and write $T(x,y) = T(x(t), y(t)) = T(t)$. Using the chain rule, we get

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}.$$

You have all terms involved, and since you want to find extreme values all you have to do is equate this to zero, find the values, and then compute the second derivative to find whether it is a minimum or not.